# How do you cleanly list all the containers in a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking to list all the containers in a pod in a script that gather's logs after running a test.  `kubectl describe pods -l k8s-app=kube-dns` returns a lot of info, but I am just looking for a return like:

```
etcd
kube2sky
skydns
```

I don't see a simple way to format the describe output.  Is there another command?  (and I guess worst case there is always parsing the output of describe).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use `get` and choose one of the supported output template with the `--output` (`-o`) flag.

Take `jsonpath` for example, 
`kubectl get pods -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o jsonpath={.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}` gives you `etcd kube2sky skydns`.

Other supported output output templates are go-template, go-template-file, jsonpath-file. See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/ for how to use jsonpath template. See https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview for how to use go template.

Update: Check this doc for other example commands to list container images: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/

Comment: If you want to see the json output, use `kubectl get pods -o json`.

Comment: If you're working with a specific pod, the command is `kubectl get pods kube-dns-q2oh6  -o jsonpath={.spec.containers[*].name}`

Comment: The OP was for one specific pod

Answer (score 220):

## Answer

```
kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name}'
```

## Explanation

This gets the JSON object representing the pod. It then uses kubectl's [JSONpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/) to extract the name of each container from the pod.

Comment: For those who want to run this command in a specific namespace then, don't forget to add `--namespace` or `-n` in this command. 

For i.e. (`kubectl -n YOUR_NAMESPACE get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name}'`)

Comment: That will not include the `initContainers`. For those you need: `kubectl -n <namespace> get pods <pod_name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.initContainers[*].name}'`

Answer (score 63):

Quick hack to avoid constructing the JSONpath query for a single pod:

```
$ kubectl logs mypod-123
a container name must be specified for pod mypod-123, choose one of: [etcd kubesky skydns]
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what it says.. a quick hack. Really useful :) Of course cannot be used in a script kind of thing. It serves the requirement.

Comment: Latest one also gives both `containers` and `init containers`

Comment: @Neo I don't see `init containers` with this way on v1.18.8 :(

Comment: I love this. The only downside is that it doesn't work for pods that have a single container. It just dumps the log for the one container.

Comment: Note that this quick hack doesn't work if the pod has annotaton `kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container` (or the deprecated annotation `kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-logs-container`)... You'll then get the log of the default container instead.

Answer (score 24):

I put some ideas together into the following:

Simple line:

```
kubectl get po -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"pod: "}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{"\tname: "}{.name}{"\n\timage: "}{.image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Split (for readability):

```
kubectl get po -o jsonpath='
    {range .items[*]}
    {"pod: "}
    {.metadata.name}
    {"\n"}{range .spec.containers[*]}
    {"\tname: "}
    {.name}
    {"\n\timage: "}
    {.image}
    {"\n"}
    {end}'
```

Comment: @EzLo I'm not sure if I like the single line format better.  I'm not a fan of having to scroll.

Comment: you can show both alternatives. Feel free to change back if you want. Using the code formatting (CTRL+K) is usually better than the quote (CTRL+Q) because of the typography, for code.

Comment: Is there a way i can have the pod name listed for each container in this format?

Comment: To avoid need of scrolling and manual search - pipe it to `less` or to `vi`: ```COMMAND | less```  or ```vi<(COMMAND)```

Comment: scrolling at stack overflow @SergeySmolnikov

Comment: The query works, Thanks! but aren't you missing an {end} element at the end?

Answer (score 24):

How to list BOTH init and non-init containers for all pods

```
kubectl get pod -o="custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,INIT-CONTAINERS:.spec.initContainers[*].name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name"
```

Output looks like this:

```
NAME                                      INIT-CONTAINERS   CONTAINERS
helm-install-traefik-sjts9                <none>            helm
metrics-server-86cbb8457f-dkpqm           <none>            metrics-server
local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-vjs6l   <none>            local-path-provisioner
coredns-6488c6fcc6-zp9gv                  <none>            coredns
svclb-traefik-f5wwh                       <none>            lb-port-80,lb-port-443
traefik-6f9cbd9bd4-pcbmz                  <none>            traefik
dc-postgresql-0                           init-chmod-data   dc-postgresql
backend-5c4bf48d6f-7c8c6                  wait-for-db       backend
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks!

Comment: Just add -A to list pods in all namespaces

Answer (score 13):

if you want a clear output of which containers are from each Pod

```
kubectl get po -l k8s-app=kube-dns \
   -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name
```

Answer (score 11):

To get the output in the separate lines (init and non-init containers):

```
kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath='{range .spec.initContainers[*]}{.name}{"\n"}{end}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Output:
base-container
sidecar-0
sidecar-1
sidecar-2

Answer (score 5):

If you use `json` as output format of [`kubectl get`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_get/) you get plenty details of a `pod`. With `json` processors like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) it is easy to select or filter for certain parts you are interested in.

To list the containers of a pod the `jq` query looks like this:

```
kubectl get --all-namespaces --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --output json pods \
  | jq --raw-output '.items[].spec.containers[].name'
```

If you want to see all details regarding one specific container try something like this:

```
kubectl get --all-namespaces --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --output json pods \
  | jq '.items[].spec.containers[] | select(.name=="etcd")'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use below command:

```
kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,Containers:.spec.containers[*].name,Image:.spec.containers[*].image
```

Answer (score 3):

To see verbose information along with configmaps of all containers in a particular pod, use this command:
`kubectl describe pod/<pod name> -n <namespace name>`

Answer (score 3):

There are enough answers here but sometimes you want to see a **deployment** object pods' **containers** and **initContainers**. To do that;

**1-** Retrieve the **deployment** name

`kubectl get deployment`

**2-** Retrieve **containers**' names

`kubectl get deployment <deployment-name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].name}'`

**3-** Retrieve **initContainers**' names

`kubectl get deployment <deployment-name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.initContainers[*].name}'`

Answer (score 2):

Use below command to see all the information of a particular pod

```
kubectl get pod <pod name> -n <namespace name> -o yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

For overall details about the pod try following command to get the container details as well

`kubectl describe pod <podname>`

Answer (score 1):

I use this to display image versions on the pods.

```
kubectl get pods  -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{end}{end}' && printf '\n'
```

It's just a small modification of script from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-by-pod), with adding new line to start next console command on the new line, removed commas at the end of each line and listing only my pods, without service pods (e.g. `--all-namespaces` option is removed).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, simple without any jsonpath (make sure to include the namespace, if needed).

To list containers for a single pod:

```
kubectl top pod podname --containers
```

Without the "podname", it lists all pods/containers:

```
kubectl top pod --containers
```

Answer (score -6):

Easiest way to know the containers in a pod:

kubectl logs  -c -n

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: I get response

error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
See 'kubectl logs -h' for help and examples